# Tails OS for Android and PC?

Tags: linux

Can I use Tails OS on a USB-stick on both an Android tablet and a PC, or do I have to have two different versions?

Would I have to go into the BIOS to make this work?

Comment: There's not really a version of Tails for Android; I've briefly explained that [here](//tor.stackexchange.com/a/963/71). There is a project to develop [such a thing](http://www.dailydot.com/technology/tor-anonymous-mobile-os-tails/) though.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an Android tablet? At the very least, your tablet & PC probably have different cpu architectures, so the exact same install/iso probably wouldn't work. And I haven't seen any Android tablets that can boot from an external drive... anyone else?

There are a few Android apps for TOR & similar tools (chat secure, etc) that may give some similar functionality as Tails has. See https://guardianproject.info/apps/

Answer (score 1):

You would need a custom image to boot from in order to install those, and currently I know of none that are specifically designed like tails is. If you had the necessary programming skills you could modify the Tails OS and MAKE it compatible with your tablet specifically, but that includes learning what hardware your tablet uses. specifically the CPU and then learning ARM assembly(Most Likely). The BIOS is just firmware that loads the OS, so yes at some point, once you have the custom image you would need to boot from the image which the BIOS would help you do. If you're interested, Offensive Security, the creators of Backtrack and Kali Linux have released a custom OS for certain NEXUS devices. It's called Kali Nethunter, and while its targeted specifically for conducting penetration tests with mobile devices, it could most certainly be used to route your connections through tor/i2p/vpn etc, thus mimicking the effects of TAILS, Although I should mention that NetHunter runs inside of its own session.